# String concatenation using C#

Tags: c#, string

I've a input string:

"risk management, portfolio management, investment planning"

How do  I convert this string into:

"risk management" + "portfolio management" + "investment planning"

Thanks.

Comment: Ambiguous questions - gotta love 'em.

Comment: Wouldn't it be string decatenation in this case?  :-)

Comment: Someone needs help on their homework. *shakes head*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Split and Trim

```
 // include linq library like this:
 // using System.Linq;
 // then

"test1, test2".Split(',').Select(o => o.Trim());
```

or

```
"test1, test2".Split(',').Select(o => o.Trim()).ToArray(); // returns array
```

and

```
"test1, test2".Split(',').Select(o => "\"" + o.Trim() + "\"")
.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + " + " + s2);

// returns a string: "test1" + "test2"
```

Comment: am now getting the output as:
"\"tax accounting\" + \"assurance services\" + \"tax audit\" + \"internal audit\" + \"lean accounting\" + \"cost accounting\"...can i get rid of the back slashes over here?

Comment: back slashes could be in a quick property view, i don't think they exist in an actual value

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Split()` method:

```
string[] phrases = s.Split(',');
```

Now you have a string array of each comma separated value.

To remove the spaces, use the `Trim()` method on each string (thanks John Feminella)

Comment: That works, but he'll have leading spaces at the beginning of every item after the first.

Answer (score 3):

```
var results = from s in string.Split("risk management, portfolio management, investment planning", new char[] { ',' })
              select s.Trim();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) in your case because you have a comma, then a space. So your strings will look like { `"risk management"`, `" portfolio management"`, `" investment planning"` }. Instead, use [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx):

```
string[] investmentServices = Regex.Split(inputString, ", ");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split the input, you can use string.Split, using comma as a delimiter or , even better ", " for taking into account the space after comma,

```
string[] array = inputString.Split(", ");
```

However, you can be wanting to replace the comma inside the string for a plus sign, this is how you could be achieving that also:

```
inputString = inputString.Replace(", ", "\" + \"");
```

Comment: The do not like "smarty pants" here.

Comment: I'm, amazed of that also, tx for upvoting

Comment: Well, I shouldn't say "only"... since we can't read his mind :) - but based on the specifications this is "most likely" what he wants, not a "smarty pants" answer...

Comment: Hmm, this solution makes assumption that leading and trailing quotes are parts of input. This is very unusual.

Comment: True, but since his input and output onto different lines we can only assume that he wants those strings manipulated verbatim. I think it's less of a stretch than assuming he wants an array of strings. Again, since there are no details no one can really know for sure

Comment: Sorry, this is a kind of ambiguous answer for an ambiguous question

Comment: i've got the answer from Koistya Navin .NET above.thanks everyone for your inputs.FYI,i did not care much about whitespaces getting trimmed or not.my main concern was not being able to add the "+" character literally in the output string which Koistya's solution achieves using Aggregate function....

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear on whether you want to replace the `','` for `'+'` or just a simple `split`.

Here are the 2 possibilities:

```
string s = "risk management, portfolio management, investment planning";

string transformedString = s.Replace(", ", "\" + \"");

string[] parts = s.Split(new [] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually looks like you're trying to perform a split, rather than concatenation.

If you're looking to take that input string and convert it into three strings containing "risk management", "portfolio management", and "investment planning", then use `string.Split(inputString, ',')`, then trim each string from the resulting array when you use it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you mean. If you need to access the CSV values then this will output each value separately...

```
string input = "risk management, portfolio management, investment planning";
string[] words = text.Split(new Char[] {','});
foreach(string word in words)
{
  Console.WriteLine(word.Trim());
}
//risk management
//portfolio management
//investment planning
```

Answer (score 0):

Reply to Jhonny D. Cano
(Sorry, don't have 50 rep for a comment.)

Your first recommendation

> string[] array = inputString.Split(", ");

Doesn't work because you can't split on a string. The closest possible overload is a char[], so you would have to write it as...

> string[] array = inputString.Split(",
>   ".ToCharArray());