# C# union with string

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I have 2 string (files path exactly) like this :

> C:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc

and

> cccc\dddd.

I would like to merge the two strings with an union operation.

For obtain :

> C:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd

How to do it ? I don't find a string method for this.
Do you think i search in the good direction or i should try with another method (split string...) ?

Thanks

Comment: In your sample results, I think you're missing the last 'c'.

Comment: How do you know its the last ;)

Comment: Look up string `concatenation`.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks, it's not simple concatenation; he wants to remove one set of "cccc" from what concatenation would yield.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String concatenation using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697950/string-concatenation-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @adv12: was merely pointing out that concatenation will be useful for this at some point.

Comment: Have you tried writing your own method? if so, could you show us what you have or is your question regarding a (possible) .NET framework component that should solve this for you?

Comment: @Neyoh. How many "segments" are likely to overlap? Is it always 1 (`cccc` in your example) or could it be 0,1, or more?

Comment: @Rob I think i always have 1 segments maybe 0.

Comment: what about aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ and ccc/eee? should it be aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee or aaa/bbb/ccc/eee/ddd or aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ccc/eee? or any other combination?

Comment: @Codeek Although seen but in my case just union end of path1 and start of path2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
var path1 = @"C:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc";
var path2 = @"cccc\dddd";

var x = string.Join(
    new string(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 1), 
    path1.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
         .Concat(path2.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
         .Distinct()
         .ToArray());

// path1 = C:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc
// path2 = cccc\dddd
// result = C:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd

// path1 = C:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd
// path2 = cccc\dddd
// result = C:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd
```

Answer (score 4):

this can get you started.  There a lot of scenarios you could CYA over , but essentially find where string two overlaps string one, then join them.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string one = @"C:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc";
    string two = @"cccc\dddd";

    int overlapIndex = one.IndexOf(two.Split('\\').First());

    string three = one.Substring(0, overlapIndex) + two;

    Console.WriteLine(three);
    // "C:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some good solutions already, just for my own reference i made a function that does this on any two strings.
Sorry that it got a litle bloated.

```
    public string Union(string one, string two)
    {
        if (one == null || two == null)
            return null;

        int idxOne = -1;
        int j = one.Length - 1;
        for (int i = two.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (two[i] == one[j])    // if the current index of string 2 matches the last character of string one, start counting
            {
                j--;
                idxOne = j;
            }
            else if (i > 0)
            {
                j = one.Length - 1;   // throw away results if match stopped  matching half-way in.
                idxOne = -1;
            }
        }
        if (idxOne != -1)
        {
            return one.Substring(0, idxOne + 1) + two;
        }

        return one + two;
    }
```

Comment: Fails for unique paths. Union for `C:\aaaa\bbbb` and `cccc\dddd` results in `C:\aaaa\bbbbcccc\dddd`.

Comment: because bbbb and cccc do not match, this function was not written  specifically for paths